# How to calculate a logistic sigmoid function in Python?

Tags: python, sigmoid

This is a logistic sigmoid function:

[image]

I know x. How can I calculate F(x) in Python now?

Let's say x = 0.458.

F(x) = ?

Answer (score 313, accepted):

This should do it:

```
import math

def sigmoid(x):
  return 1 / (1 + math.exp(-x))
```

And now you can test it by calling:

```
>>> sigmoid(0.458)
0.61253961344091512
```

**Update**: Note that the above was mainly intended as a straight one-to-one translation of the given expression into Python code. It is *not* tested or known to be a numerically sound implementation. If you know you need a very robust implementation, I'm sure there are others where people have actually given this problem some thought.

Comment: Just because I need it so often to try little things: `sigmoid = lambda x: 1 / (1 + math.exp(-x))`

Comment: This does not work for extreme negative values of x.  I was using this unfortunate implementation until I noticed it was creating NaNs.

Comment: If you replace `math.exp` with `np.exp` you won't get NaNs, although you will get runtime warnings.

Comment: Using `math.exp` with numpy array can yield some errors, like: `TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars`. To avoid it you should use `numpy.exp`.

Comment: Can numerical instability be mitigated simply by adding `x = max(-709,x)` before the expression?

Answer (score 250):

It is also available in scipy: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.logistic.html

```
In [1]: from scipy.stats import logistic

In [2]: logistic.cdf(0.458)
Out[2]: 0.61253961344091512
```

which is only a costly wrapper (because it allows you to scale and translate the logistic function) of another scipy function:

```
In [3]: from scipy.special import expit

In [4]: expit(0.458)
Out[4]: 0.61253961344091512
```

**If you are concerned about performances continue reading, otherwise just use [`expit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.expit.html).**

### Some benchmarking:

```
In [5]: def sigmoid(x):
  ....:     return 1 / (1 + math.exp(-x))
  ....: 

In [6]: %timeit -r 1 sigmoid(0.458)
1000000 loops, best of 1: 371 ns per loop


In [7]: %timeit -r 1 logistic.cdf(0.458)
10000 loops, best of 1: 72.2 µs per loop

In [8]: %timeit -r 1 expit(0.458)
100000 loops, best of 1: 2.98 µs per loop
```

As expected `logistic.cdf` is (much) slower than `expit`. `expit` is still slower than the python `sigmoid` function when called with a single value because it is a universal function written in C ( http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html ) and thus has a call overhead. This overhead is bigger than the computation speedup of `expit` given by its compiled nature when called with a single value. But it becomes negligible when it comes to big arrays:

```
In [9]: import numpy as np

In [10]: x = np.random.random(1000000)

In [11]: def sigmoid_array(x):                                        
   ....:    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))
   ....:
```

(You'll notice the tiny change from `math.exp` to `np.exp` (the first one does not support arrays, but is much faster if you have only one value to compute))

```
In [12]: %timeit -r 1 -n 100 sigmoid_array(x)
100 loops, best of 1: 34.3 ms per loop

In [13]: %timeit -r 1 -n 100 expit(x)
100 loops, best of 1: 31 ms per loop
```

But when you really need performance, a common practice is to have a precomputed table of the the sigmoid function that hold in RAM, and trade some precision and memory for some speed (for example: http://radimrehurek.com/2013/09/word2vec-in-python-part-two-optimizing/ )

Also, note that `expit` implementation is numerically stable since version 0.14.0: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/3385

Comment: By using floats (1.) instead of ints (1) in your sigmoid function you would reduce running time by ~10%

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean (floats are used in the examples), but in any case one rarely computes a sigmoid on intergers.

Comment: What kd88 meant to say was that the numeric literals you used in your function (1) are parsed as integers, and have to be cast at runtime to floats. You would get better performance using floating point literals (1.0).

Comment: You can always vectorize the function so it would support arrays.

Comment: you want to talk about an expensive wrapper? %timeit -r 1 expit(0.458)

%timeit -r 1 1/(1+np.exp(0.458))

Comment: I benchmarked vectorizing 10000 datapoints as a vector compared to one at a time with expit.  Not even close 2-3 orders of magnatude faster.

Answer (score 61):

Here's how you would implement the logistic sigmoid in a numerically stable way (as described [here](http://timvieira.github.io/blog/post/2014/02/11/exp-normalize-trick/)):

```
def sigmoid(x):
    "Numerically-stable sigmoid function."
    if x >= 0:
        z = exp(-x)
        return 1 / (1 + z)
    else:
        z = exp(x)
        return z / (1 + z)
```

Or perhaps this is more accurate:

```
import numpy as np

def sigmoid(x):  
    return np.exp(-np.logaddexp(0, -x))
```

Internally, it implements the same condition as above, but then uses `log1p`.

In general, the multinomial logistic sigmoid is:

```
def nat_to_exp(q):
    max_q = max(0.0, np.max(q))
    rebased_q = q - max_q
    return np.exp(rebased_q - np.logaddexp(-max_q, np.logaddexp.reduce(rebased_q)))
```

[(However, `logaddexp.reduce` could be more accurate.)](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/4260)

Comment: referring to the multinomial logistic sigmoid (softmax), if I also wanted a [temperature parameter for Reinforcement learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function#Reinforcement_learning), does it suffice to divide `max_q` and `rebased_q` by `tau` ? because I tried that and I don't get probabilities that sum to 1

Comment: @CiprianTomoiaga If you want to have a temperature, just divide your evidence (`q`) by your temperature.  rebased_q can be anything: it doesn't change the answer; it improves the numerical stability.

Comment: are you sure `nat_to_exp` is equivalent to softmax (as you mentioned in your other answer) ? Copy-paste of it returns probabilities that don't sum to 1

Comment: @CiprianTomoiaga The short answer is that I omit the final component of the input and the output, so you'll have to calculate it if you want it as one minus the sum of the rest.  The more statistical explanation is that the categorical distribution has n-1 natural parameters or n-1 expectation parameters.

Comment: makes sense, kind of. Care to ellaborate on [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41902047/how-to-calculate-robust-softmax-function-with-temperature)?

Comment: Didn't you mean `np.exp(-np.logaddexp(0, -x))`? (note `np` instead of `math`)

Comment: @yuval if `x` is a `float`, using math is a bit faster.

Comment: Got it. My concern was that `math` does not work on arrays

Comment: First one could be written as:
`def sigmoid(x):
    "Numerically-stable sigmoid function."
    z = exp(-x) if x >= 0 else exp(x)
    return z / (1 + z)`

Comment: @DesiréDeWaele  I think you missed the difference in the second statement.

Answer (score 11):

Another way by transforming the `tanh` function:

```
sigmoid = lambda x: .5 * (math.tanh(.5 * x) + 1)
```

Comment: @NeilG Mathematically, sigmoid(x) == (1 + tanh(x/2))/2. So this is a valid solution, though the numerically stabilised methods are superior.

Answer (score 9):

I feel many might be interested in free parameters to alter the shape of the sigmoid function. Second for many applications you want to use a mirrored sigmoid function. Third you might want to do a simple normalization for example the output values are between 0 and 1.

Try:

```
def normalized_sigmoid_fkt(a, b, x):
   '''
   Returns array of a horizontal mirrored normalized sigmoid function
   output between 0 and 1
   Function parameters a = center; b = width
   '''
   s= 1/(1+np.exp(b*(x-a)))
   return 1*(s-min(s))/(max(s)-min(s)) # normalize function to 0-1
```

And to draw and compare:

```
def draw_function_on_2x2_grid(x): 
    fig, ((ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4)) = plt.subplots(2, 2)
    plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=.5)
    plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=.5)

    ax1.plot(x, normalized_sigmoid_fkt( .5, 18, x))
    ax1.set_title('1')

    ax2.plot(x, normalized_sigmoid_fkt(0.518, 10.549, x))
    ax2.set_title('2')

    ax3.plot(x, normalized_sigmoid_fkt( .7, 11, x))
    ax3.set_title('3')

    ax4.plot(x, normalized_sigmoid_fkt( .2, 14, x))
    ax4.set_title('4')
    plt.suptitle('Different normalized (sigmoid) function',size=10 )

    return fig
```

Finally:

```
x = np.linspace(0,1,100)
Travel_function = draw_function_on_2x2_grid(x)
```

[image: Sigmoid functions graph]

Answer (score 8):

Use the numpy package to allow your sigmoid function to parse vectors.

In conformity with Deeplearning, I use the following code:

```
import numpy as np
def sigmoid(x):
    s = 1/(1+np.exp(-x))
    return s
```

Answer (score 7):

another way

```
>>> def sigmoid(x):
...     return 1 /(1+(math.e**-x))
...
>>> sigmoid(0.458)
```

Comment: What is the difference between this and unwind's function? Is math.e**-x better than math.exp(-x)?

Comment: There is no difference in terms of output result. If you want to know the difference in terms of speed, you can use timeit to time their execution. But that's really not important.

Comment: `pow` is often implemented in terms of `exp` and `log`, so using `exp` directly is almost certainly better.

Comment: This suffers from overflows when `x` is very negative.

Answer (score 3):

Good answer from @unwind. It however can't handle extreme negative number (throwing OverflowError).

My improvement:

```
def sigmoid(x):
    try:
        res = 1 / (1 + math.exp(-x))
    except OverflowError:
        res = 0.0
    return res
```

Comment: This is better, but you are still suffering from numerical percussion issues with negative values.

Answer (score 3):

Tensorflow includes also a `sigmoid` function:
https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.2/api_docs/python/tf/sigmoid

```
import tensorflow as tf

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
x = 0.458
y = tf.sigmoid(x)

u = y.eval()
print(u)
# 0.6125396
```

Comment: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.sigmoid_kernel.html

Answer (score 3):

A numerically stable version of the logistic sigmoid function.

```
    def sigmoid(x):
        pos_mask = (x >= 0)
        neg_mask = (x < 0)
        z = np.zeros_like(x,dtype=float)
        z[pos_mask] = np.exp(-x[pos_mask])
        z[neg_mask] = np.exp(x[neg_mask])
        top = np.ones_like(x,dtype=float)
        top[neg_mask] = z[neg_mask]
        return top / (1 + z)
```

Comment: if x is positive we are simply using 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x)) but when x is negative we are using the function np.exp(x) / (1 + np.exp(x)) instead of using 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))  because when x is negative -x will be positive so np.exp(-x) can explode due to large value of -x.

Answer (score 2):

A one liner...

```
In[1]: import numpy as np

In[2]: sigmoid=lambda x: 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))

In[3]: sigmoid(3)
Out[3]: 0.9525741268224334
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Vectorized method when using `pandas DataFrame/Series` or `numpy array`:

The top answers are optimized methods for single point calculation, but when you want to apply these methods to a pandas series or numpy array, it requires `apply`, which is basically for loop in the background and will iterate over every row and apply the method. This is quite inefficient.

To speed up our code, we can make use of vectorization and numpy broadcasting:

```
x = np.arange(-5,5)
np.divide(1, 1+np.exp(-x))

0    0.006693
1    0.017986
2    0.047426
3    0.119203
4    0.268941
5    0.500000
6    0.731059
7    0.880797
8    0.952574
9    0.982014
dtype: float64
```

Or with a `pandas Series`:

```
x = pd.Series(np.arange(-5,5))
np.divide(1, 1+np.exp(-x))
```

Comment: Or just pass the numpy array into expit.

Answer (score 1):

you can calculate it as :

```
import math
def sigmoid(x):
  return 1 / (1 + math.exp(-x))
```

or conceptual, deeper and without any imports:

```
def sigmoid(x):
  return 1 / (1 + 2.718281828 ** -x)
```

or you can use numpy for matrices:

```
import numpy as np #make sure numpy is already installed
def sigmoid(x):
  return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply declare `1 / np.exp(x)` if putting **-** before **x** confuse you.

```
def sigmoid(x):
     return 1 /(1 + 1 / np.exp(x))

sigmoid(0.458)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

def sigmoid(x):
    s = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))
    return s

result = sigmoid(0.467)
print(result)
```

The above code is the logistic sigmoid function in python.
If I know that `x = 0.467` ,
The sigmoid function, `F(x) = 0.385`. You can try to substitute any value of x you know in the above code, and you will get a different value of `F(x)`.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the python function to do the same.

```
def sigmoid(x) :
    return 1.0/(1+np.exp(-x))
```