# numpy.linalg.LinAlgError: Singular matrix Error When Trying to Solve

Tags: python, numpy, pycharm

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]])
B = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]])
C = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
D = np.array([[1], [2], [3]])

prod_AB = np.matmul(A, B)
E = np.matmul(prod_AB, C)

x = np.linalg.solve(E, D)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Owner.ASUS-DESKTOP/Documents/ENGR 102/Lab 10/test.py", line 11, in <module>
    x = np.linalg.solve(E, D)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in solve
  File "C:\Users\Owner.ASUS-DESKTOP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py", line 394, in solve
    r = gufunc(a, b, signature=signature, extobj=extobj)
  File "C:\Users\Owner.ASUS-DESKTOP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py", line 88, in _raise_linalgerror_singular
    raise LinAlgError("Singular matrix")
numpy.linalg.LinAlgError: Singular matrix
```

Why is this throwing an error? My colleagues used a different IDE (I am using PyCharm and they are using Anaconda) and there program ran no problem. Is this error IDE dependant?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not IDE dependent. Your `A` matrix is singular, with one of its singular values equal to zero. That means its determinant is equal to zero. When you multiply `A` with `B` the resulting matrix is also singular and then you multiply by `C` to get `E`. That means that `E` is also singular (if you multiply two matrices and at least one of them is singular the result is always singular). We can confirm this by looking at the singular values of `E` with

```py
print(np.linalg.svd(E)[1])
```

which prints in my machine

```
[3.14537743e+03 9.15629385e-01 9.92880407e-17]
```

Notice that the last singular value is essentially zero.

Then you try to solve te system `Ex = D`, but because `E` is singular you get the `numpy.linalg.LinAlgError: Singular matrix` error. Note that since `E` is 3x3 you are trying to solve a 3x3 linear system of equations. Since you only have 2 singular values different from zero the matrix rank is 2. That means that your corresponding linear system has 3 variables, but only
two equations. Therefore you have no unique solution and `np.linalg.solve` fails.

---

**Your linear system actually has infinite solutions**. While you can't take the inverse of `E`, you still can solve the system to find **one of the solutions**. A common way to do that is using the method of [least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares). Instead of solving `Ex = D` the method of least squares finds an `x` that minimizes the squared norm-2 of `Ex - D`. You can computed with numpy as

```py
x = np.linalg.lstsq(E, D, rcond=None)[0]
```

We can't confirm this is one solution with

```
print(E@x)
```

which prints

```
[[1.]
 [2.]
 [3.]]
```

Comment: That is easy to verify since det(A . B) = det(A) . det(B). If the first determinant is 0, it propagates all the way to the end.

Answer (score 0):

The first step of diagnosis is to print the offending values, to wit, `E` and its determinant:

```
[[ 290  400  510]
 [ 674  928 1182]
 [1058 1456 1854]]
0.0
```

The matrix is singular, so it cannot be inverted; there are either no solutions or an infinite number.

We can't answer why your classmates get a different answer, since you haven't provided their solution data.